How to permanently delete files in qBittorrent v5?
Prior to the recently released v5, when I selected a torrent, hit Shift+Delete, then clicked Remove, the files would be permanently deleted.
But in v5.0.0 (64-bit), the above actions instead merely move the files to Recycle Bin.
How do I restore the old behavior?
(I'm using Windows 11 Home 23H2.)

To permanently delete content, as well as .torrent file, rather than moving content to the Recycle bin, set that in the Options | Advanced dialog.

Set Torrent content removing mode to Delete files permanently.
